# Informatica - Adding a new column with multiple conditions in an existing mapping

Tags: informatica, iif

I'm new to ETL and would need some help on the below:

I have an existing mapping which generates CSV extracts. To this I have to add a new column which is derived from the data that is existing the current data extracts.

I have about 7 conditions to check for e.g.:

colA is not null, colB >'7/1/2006', colC != 'Implementation' colD in('dsa','cpu') etc.

Lets say currently I have about 100 records in my extracts. I have to now add a new column to my final extracts such that the values for this new column is generated only on satisfying all the above conditions. Else the new column would have NULL values.

How do I implement this?

Should I write a query or use an exp or a filter?

Comment: Use an expression

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done by using an expression transformation.
Add a new new column in the expression and place your logic into that.
Now map that column from expression transformation to the new column in the target.

There are 2 approaches to get the NULL value
1) In the if else logic, make it as NULL in the else part
2) You can use a column default value in expression.